# error opening windows phone 7.1 files

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I downloaded sample files from windows phone samples and tried opening it with visual studio ultimate 13 (am using Win8 Pro X64) and get the following error

`C:\Users\Erick\Downloads\Browser Downloads\Model-View-ViewModel Sample\C#\sdkMVVMCS\sdkMVVMCS.csproj : error  : The expression "[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText(C:\Users\Erick\Downloads\Browser Downloads\Model-View-ViewModel Sample\C#\sdkMVVMCS)" cannot be evaluated. Access to the path 'C:\Users\Erick\Downloads\Browser Downloads\Model-View-ViewModel Sample\C#\sdkMVVMCS' is denied.  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Silverlight for Phone\v4.0\Microsoft.Silverlight.Common.targets`

I also tried opening the file with VS express 12 and Visual Studio 10 all in my computer and get an error. VS express 12 doesnot open while The error in Visual Studio 10 is as below

`C:\Users\Erick\Downloads\Browser Downloads\Model-View-ViewModel Sample(1)\C#\sdkMVVMCS\sdkMVVMCS.csproj : error  : The project file 'C:\Users\Erick\Downloads\Browser Downloads\Model-View-ViewModel Sample(1)\C#\sdkMVVMCS\sdkMVVMCS.csproj' cannot be opened.`

`The project type is not supported by this installation.`

Kindly need immediate assistance.

Thanks,

The download link for the file is http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Model-View-ViewModel-Sample-8cb92fd9/file/62775/10/Model-View-ViewModel%20Sample.zip

Comment: "Access to the path ... is denied"? You might want to check permissions on that folder.

Comment: from the windows explorer permissions are OK. some other files (project from WP8 samples) downloaded can be open but some cannot including the i am trying to open. Thanks

Comment: You should try starting Visual Studio in administrator mode, just to make sure.

Comment: tried it and it failed.

Comment: Rightclick on the file failed to open and check if the file came from another computer and might be blocked. If so press `unblock`

Comment: thanks, Tried unblocking the zip file and i still get the same error.